# Is EclipseLink a viable option for multi-tenant JPA for a rapidly developing product?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I work on a product which would like to adopt JPA for persistence, but which supports both schema per tenant and shared schema (discriminator columns) persistence.

It looks as if support for JPA 2.0 multi-tenancy capabilities is a bit sparse out there. EclipseLink seems the most suitable.

However I am concerned that EclipseLink itself seems rather inactive - I am struggling to find any documents etc dating more recently than 2012. This makes me rather dubious that it is a viable option for us.

Is EclipseLink a viable option for multi-tenant JPA for a rapidly developing product?

Comment: As EclipseLink is the reference implementation for both JPA 2.0 and 2.1, I don't think there would be a problem. By the way the last release was in last April

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/releases/index.php) you can find the history of all releases, you'll see that last release was Jul 4th, 2014 (version `2.5.2`), so EclipseLink is under active development. To be honest, version `2.6.0` was scheduled for December 1st 2014, but it wasn't released for some reason.

Check [this](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/a_multitenant.htm) for examples on supported multitenancy types.

One thing to note is that Hibernate has a much larger community (for example, on StackOverflow there are over 40k questions tagged with `hibernate`, compared to only 3k `eclipselink` questions). That could mean a lot in case of a problem that needs community help.